# Why isnt the variable isValid updating properly?

Tags: javascript

Ok so i have to run registration form against jsonplaceholder users to see if there are duplicate and return "Registration Complete" or "User Already Exists"

```
if(isValid)
    {

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(users => {
        users.forEach(function(user){
                if(user.username==usersname){
                isValid=false;
                }
            });
        });
        
        
        if(isValid){
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("success");
            x[0].innerHTML="";
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName("errExist");
            y[0].innerHTML="Registration Complete";
        }else{
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("errExist");
            x[0].innerHTML="";
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName("success");
            y[0].innerHTML="User Already Exists";
        }
    }
```

This is the code, but for whatever reason isValid always remains "True" despite me knowing that it enters the if(user.username==usersname). It always shows "Registration Complete". Can someone explain why that is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the dom code inside .then(), otherwise, it is executed before you getting fetch request (async operation)

```
if (isValid) {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((users) => {
      users.forEach(function (user) {
        if (user.username == usersname) {
          isValid = false;
        }
      });

      if (isValid) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("success");
        x[0].innerHTML = "";
        var y = document.getElementsByClassName("errExist");
        y[0].innerHTML = "Registration Complete";
      } else {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("errExist");
        x[0].innerHTML = "";
        var y = document.getElementsByClassName("success");
        y[0].innerHTML = "User Already Exists";
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is an async function.
While it runs, the rest of the code runs as well.
Hence, `isValid` is actually updated after checking the condition already.

You should either move the if condition to be inside the last `.then` inside `fetch` or use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).